# paypal rest api credentials possible security issue?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

According to the example in the java SDK:

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-java

the clientID, clientSecret are retrieved from the sdk_config.properties file, where they reside as plain text.
e.g. The properties file that comes with the java SDK:

```
# Connection Information
http.ConnectionTimeOut=5000
http.Retry=1
http.ReadTimeOut=30000
http.MaxConnection=100

# HTTP Proxy configuration
# If you are using proxy set http.UseProxy to true and replace the following values with your proxy parameters
http.ProxyPort=8080
http.ProxyHost=127.0.0.1
http.UseProxy=false
http.ProxyUserName=null
http.ProxyPassword=null

#Set this property to true if you are using the PayPal SDK within a Google App Engine java app
http.GoogleAppEngine = false

# Service Configuration
service.EndPoint=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
# Live EndPoint
# service.EndPoint=https://api.paypal.com

# Credentials
clientID=EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM
clientSecret=EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM
```

Isn't it a security issue?
Are there better alternatives for storing these credentials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff here from PayPal.  I'd like to know what your concerns are about a security issue, so I can more specifically address them.  I'll address what I think you are concerned about.

These credentials need to live somewhere on the server that communicates with PayPal for transactions to work.  You do not want to share the `clientSecret` to the outside world, so of course, you wouldn't want this file to be accessible via any public web endpoint.

If you're worried about your developers or operation folks getting access to this secret, then I might suggest implementing a deploy process where the production machine is only visible to a select set of trusted people, and populating the correct set of credentials in this file at deploy time only.

Comment: Hi Jeff, what i meant is that when we want to protect sensitive data e.g. passwords, we hash them and then save them to DB.
Here the sensitive data is in plain text and anyone who might gain access to this config file can perform operations on behalf of this paypal account.

Comment: Yes, you'll want to only allow trusted developers or operations folks to access the secret.  It's up to you to create a reasonable deploy process where this secret is not exposed to untrusted individuals.  If the credentials are ever compromised, you can always delete the app on developer.paypal.com, and create a new one.

Comment: That's a somewhat weird approach, because in the case of passwords (that are being hashed), even if some hacker succeeds in getting it, it's meaningless to him since it's hashed.
But here, it's still plain text, so if it's hacked - the sensitive data can be used as is.